# What is this color model : 0.094117647058823528, 0.10196078431372549, 0.10588235294117647?

Tags: colors, color-codes

The following command picks a color on screen (only way I found to be working on Debian sid / Wayland/Gnome 42.1) :

`gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.Shell.Screenshot --object-path /org/gnome/Shell/Screenshot --method org.gnome.Shell.Screenshot.PickColor`

But the output is

> ({'color': <(0.094117647058823528, 0.10196078431372549, 0.10588235294117647)>},)

What is the color model here and how I can convert it to rgb or html colors ?

Comment: It is possible that it is RGB. Values 0 to 1 (and allowing "overflow the white") is much better then having a integer maximum value (especially for professional use, where you may get more then 256 reds)

Comment: Steven, when I multiply each number by 255 (and round them) I do get the same color in RGB, thanks !

Comment: Please, do not use "same colour in RGB". You were brave enough to use "colour model" instead of "colour space" (RGB is a colour model, but to get the same colours, you need to use the same colour space. Probably you are using sRGB (the PC and web colours). And sRGB can work also with 10 bits (so white is 1024, 1024, 1024)